# How do i get data into Php Array for webpack?

Tags: php, webpack, webpack-2, loader

Good day

1. I am install php loader for webpack

   [php loader for webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-php-loader)
2. Files

index.js

```
    let fileContent = require('php!./index.php');
```

---

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {

module: {
loaders: [
{
test: /\.php$/,
loaders: [
  'html-minify',
  'php-loader'
  ]
 },
]},
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
return [
    'bar' => 'foo',
    'foo' => 'bar',
];
```

run webpack

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'php' in 
'C:\local\php'
 @ ./index.js 6:18-44
```

Why webpack can't see this php file ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKcwI.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDAy6.png)

Comment: Where did you put the php file? Can you show me the structure of your files?

Comment: It is test project. All files located in the root directories

I am attache picture in the question and here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSq0c.png

Comment: It should be `require('./index.php')` remove the `php!`

Comment: thank you, When  i remove php. It is code is work(works whith '!./index.php'), but my php file when reads fail. What is the problem ? I had think it is be JSON string...


 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDAy6.png